# OpenLDAP: Retrieve parent DN

Tags: openldap

What I have:

I have following hierarchy in my openldap setup. 
Account '1-AA' has a user 'Foo'. 
Base DN is

```
o=MyCompany,dc=sanjose,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=edu
```

Account is directly under Base DN.

What I want:

I want to display what is the account id (here 1-AA) for user 'Foo'.

What I know/tried:

Using standard java ldap search as

```
env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://<host>:<port>/dc=sanjose,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=edu");
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("o=MyCompany",
                "(user=Foo)", getSimpleSearchControls());
//hasNext loop
SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
System.out.println(result.getNameInNamespace());
```

Now the problem is that no result is returned in the above case. But if I try to get DN for Account 1-AA by changing search query to

```
NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("o=MyCompany",
                "(Account=1-AA)", getSimpleSearchControls());
```

it works fine.

How can I get the parent DN here. In English I just want to say give me all the Account Ids for while user=Foo.

Comment: is the attribute `user` a `DN`?

Comment: No. user is just an attribute say for custom objectClass COMPANYUSERS. DN could be something like "user=Foo,Account=1-AA,o=MyCompany,dc=sanjose,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=edu" for the user Foo entry

Comment: Could you please paste few example of how a `user` attribute looks like in your directory?

Comment: Not sure how that would help in debugging my issue but here is an example.  username=testuser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming searching for `(user=Foo)` does return the entry `user=Foo,Account=1-AA,o=MyCompany,dc=sanjose,dc=corp,dc=company,dc=edu`, then `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName` can get you the rest of the way. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/ldapname.html has an example of taking a prefix or suffix from a DN.